# How to get element css in directive without using jQuery?

Tags: angularjs

I try to write loader with AngularJS by using directive and spin.js (that doesn't use jQuery).

I know that AngularJS has own jQuery lite. However I can't fetch `width` from `element` in directive.

Basically I need get button width (inside directive)

I tried so far:

```
element[0].width  // < - error
angular.element(element[0]).css('width')  // < - undefined
```

Here we go:

Demo in <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DKnpgUKRtSjsJCrt9svb?p=preview)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
 <button type="submit" loader left="5" ng-click="loadData()" >Load Data</button>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, stockData, $timeout) {


  $scope.loadData = function(){

    $scope.init();

            stockData.query()
                        .then(function (result) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $scope.data = result.data;

                            $scope.stop();
                            return result.data;
                        }, 3000);
                    }, function (result) {
                        alert("Error: No data returned");
                    });   
               }
      });


app.directive('loader', ['$parse',  'stockData', '$timeout', function ($parse, stockData, $timeout) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            var spinner;

             var opts = {
                lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
                length: 3, // The length of each line
                width: 2, // The line thickness
                radius: 7, // The radius of the inner circle
                corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
                rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
                direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
                color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
                speed: 1.3, // Rounds per second
                trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
                shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
                hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
                className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
                zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
                top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
                left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
            };


               target = element[0];

              scope.init = function(){
               attr.$set('disabled', true);


             if(attr['left'] != undefined){

               var left_ = parseInt(attr['left']);

             console.log(element[0].width); // < - error
             console.log(angular.element(element[0]).css('width')); // < - undefined


               if(left_ >= 0){
                 //opts.left = element.width() + parseInt(attr['left']);
               }
               else{
                // opts.left =  -element.width()/2  + parseInt(attr['left']);
               }
             }  

               spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
            }; 

            scope.stop =  function(){
              attr.$set('disabled', false);
              spinner.stop();
            };
        }
    };
}]);


app.factory('stockData', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

    var factory = {
        query: function () {
             // dummy call
            var data = $http.get('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json');
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(data);
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    }
    return factory;
}]);
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `element[0].offsetWidth`

`.css('width')` will be undefined as you don't have any **inline** CSS defining the width, and `.width` is a jQuery thing.

`angular.element` uses a 'jqLite' if jQuery isn't available, which only offers a subset of the functionality. Computed CSS style is not one of these things (and [won't be any time soon](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8161#issuecomment-49212483) due to performance implications).

There's a decent reference for what you can do without jQuery [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements)

Comment: Isn't this a getter though? In jQuery you can get style properties with .css( propertyName )

Comment: In jQuery, yes, but angular's jqlite doesn't support this due to it being a fairly expensive operation to perform. See [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8161#issuecomment-49212483) for more information. JQLite only returns inline style with `.css(..)`

Answer (score 6):

`element[0].getBoundingClientRect()` is another powerful API.

You can get `bottom`, `height`, `left`, `right`, `top`, `width` by calling:

```
element[0].getBoundingClientRect()
```

Answer (score 2):

For those of you interested in retrieving an arbitrary CSS property,
you can access the CSS style of an Angular element in a directive's link function by

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(element[0]),
```

And then access the value of any CSS rule like such:

```
var color = style.getPropertyValue('color');
```